# Issues with sympy simplify / factor / collect

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, simplify

I can't get the simplify function to simplify the trigonometric identities when integrals of functions are present. I put a simple example where it does not work as expected.

```py
from IPython.display import display
from sympy import *

# Symbolic constants
z = symbols('z')
R = symbols('R')
theta = symbols('theta')

# Functions
phi_x = Function('\phi_x')(z)
phi_y = Function('\phi_y')(z)
m = Function('m')(z)

expr = sin(theta)**2*integrate(phi_y**2*m, (z, 0, R)) + cos(theta)**2*integrate(phi_y**2*m, (z, 0, R)) + integrate(phi_x**2*m, (z, 0, R))
expr = simplify(expr)
display(expr)
```

I get:

```py
[out]:sin(theta)**2*Integral(\phi_y(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R)) + cos(theta)**2*Integral(\phi_y(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R)) + Integral(\phi_x(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R))
```

While the expected is the trigonometric identity to be simplified:

```py
[expected]: Integral(\phi_y(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R)) + Integral(\phi_x(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R))
```

Comment: In my testing it's the third integral that's keeping `simplify` from working.  Apply `simplify` to just the first two terms. `simplify` is a complex function (module), so it's hard to know exactly what heuristic(s) it uses.

Comment: The case above is just an example, the equations I am working with are significantly longer although the identities are essentially simple. So I really need to do it automatically, simplifying manually defies the whole purpose of using sympy. I guess the problem is in the factor function subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since trigsimp will simplify `a*cos(x)**2 + a*sin(x)**2 + b` if you replace your Integrals with symbols it should work. One way is this:

```
>>> mask = {i: Dummy() for i in expr.atoms(Integral)}
>>> trigsimp(expr.xreplace(mask)).xreplace({v:k for k,v in mask.items()})
Integral(x0*\phi_y(z)**2, (z, 0, R)) + Integral(\phi_x(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R))
```

But I think `cse` is, in general, better since if there is not a common expression in front of the trig terms then they won't (likely) simplify anyway:

```
>>> r, e = cse(expr)
>>> trigsimp(e[0]).xreplace(dict(reversed(r)))
Integral(x0*\phi_y(z)**2, (z, 0, R)) + Integral(\phi_x(z)**2*m(z), (z, 0, R))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you solved not only my problem with the integrals, but possibly also another issue I am experiencing with the speed in simplifying a system of large equations. :)